# Outputting user input - preventing for xss

Tags: php, xss, htmlspecialchars

I have an admin section within my site where items can be stored. Once they are stored, they are displayed on the front end. Part of my display involves code like the following:

```
echo "<p>".$rose['description']."</p>";
```

Does this need to have htmlspecialchars included into it to protect from xss at a low level?

Comment: Have you tested yourself? You could at least test for `<script type="text/javascript">alert("HI");</script>` in `$row['description']` and see if it alerts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course, you should always santize user input before outputting it back to prevent XSS attacks. remember that you should sanitize user input before outputting it and not before saving it to the db, because you don't always need to output html

Comment: (But the appropriate sanitization is not always `htmlspecialchars`, depending on the output context.)

Comment: so would this be sufficient: echo htmlspecialchars "<p>".$rose['description']."</p>"

Comment: @user1278496 you would need echo "<p>". htmlspecialchars ($rose['description'])."</p>"